# Is it possible to connect to Azure Devops from Visual Studio 2010 on Windows XP

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-xp

I get all kind of different answers searching in the internet but it seems there is no definite answer...so simply i have a Windows XP workstation with Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and i just can't connect to Azure Devops to have my project under source control.
Anyone succeeded with the same setup ?

Comment: Most services now require TLS 1.2, which is not implemented in Windows XP. Let it die peacefully and upgrade your workstation.

Comment: If its up to me i would probably toss it out of the window..but not..thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Select **Team > Manage Connections...** from the file menu.
2. In the Team Explorer menu that pops up, click the-drop down option that says **Manage Connections > Connect to a Project...**
3. In the dialog that pops up, click the link that says **Add TFS Server** and a new textbox should appear.
4. Enter the URL for your Azure Devops server and click Add.

From there, you should be able to see the list of projects on your server and connect that project to Visual Studio.